# Which is the feasible solution to store Multiple Id's from checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database table `prop_amenities` which have following columns

[image]

here is the create table i am using for the above table

```
CREATE TABLE `prop_amenities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amenity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `propAmenities` (`amenity_id`,`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i will be storing multiple amenity id's for a single property_id, here is the example of the values i have stored.

[image]

however this works just fine while inserting, but while updating it is a real problem, if for example i have to delete and add more amenity_id i have to perform two database trip first delete the value and then add the new one.

to make it feel nicer i thought of using `serialize()` or `json_encode()` to store the array of amenity_id in database. this way i could reduce the number of column i.e it will be one column per property_id.

Database column after using `serialize()` [image]

What do you think which solution better fits the situation here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask yourself if you will ever need to care in a query which ones are selected. If the answer is an absolute "no" then serialization is acceptable. Otherwise, stick to the properly-normalized form.

Comment: by ones do you mean to say single column or one value?

Comment: i am sorry for my poor english. but i am unable to understand what you mean to say. do you mean i should only be using serialization only if i will have the situation where i will select more then one checkboxes?

Comment: No. You should avoid serialization if you need to query which, if any, of the checkboxes have been selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have more than 64 possible amenities, the [SET datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) would work nicely to contain all the amenities for a particular property in a single column, while being much easier to query than a serialized value would be.